# Clipping Rasters with a mask layer error

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, masking

I've got a NDVI layer that I'm trying to clip with a vector file but when I try and use GDAL Tools clipper I get an error.  That shows up like this:

What am I doing wrong?  This is before I even pick the mask layer!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QUANTU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetPluginBase.py", line 28, in someValueChanged
    self.emit(SIGNAL("valuesChanged(const QStringList &)"), self.getArguments())
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QUANTU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\doClipper.py", line 105, in getArguments
    return self.getArgsModeMask()
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QUANTU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\doClipper.py", line 143, in getArgsModeMask
    if self.alphaBandCheck.isChecked():
TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable

Python version:
2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
1.7.3-Wroclaw Wroclaw, 00624b3

Python path: ['C:\Users\dean.walker\.qgis\python\plugins\GeoCoding', 'C:\Users\dean.walker\.qgis\python\plugins\GeoCoding', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QUANTU~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/dean.walker/.qgis/python', 'C:/Users/dean.walker/.qgis/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QUANTU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\bin\python25.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\Python25\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', '/usr/share/qgis/python', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Comment: could you please share the code itself?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Is the native CRS of the raster file the same as the native CRS of the vector file that you are using to clip it?

Comment: No, the CRS are not the same for the files.  One is 4326 and the other is 32611.  How do I show you the code itself? I'm not familiar with how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The CRS of the raster layer and the CRS of the vector layer have to be the same. Probably the best thing to do is to reproject the vector layer (I'm guessing this is the EPSG:4326 one). Right-click on the layer in the layer panel and go Save As.. and select EPSG:32611 as the target CRS.

[image]

Comment: Still no good.  Throwing the same error at me.

Comment: You've reprojected the vector layer so that it now has the same CRS as the raster layer. So, the next thing to do is to disable on-the-fly coordinate transformation and then load both layers. Can you confirm that if you do this the layers align properly on the screen? N.

Comment: Yes,  They line up with "on the fly projection" unchecked in the project properties.

Comment: Is it possible to post a link to the two files? I had several problems with QGIS 1.7.3 and it would be nice to try clipping in 1.8 (before suggesting that you upgrade). N.

Comment: Yup, Let me get them posted up and I'll post a link

Comment: Ok, Here is the links to the files:

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/FHB03nCmrV/  NDVI Tiff

Comment: 1.  http://www.fileswap.com/dl/QsDbrIe0QX/  Alans .shx           2.  http://www.fileswap.com/dl/QG6OXHo5J/  Alans.shp                 3.  http://www.fileswap.com/dl/BmpLCoI44l/  Alans.qpj            4.  http://www.fileswap.com/dl/eauWVKOMOZ/   Alans.prj            5.   http://www.fileswap.com/dl/D6WVwt5nIy/  Alans. dbf

Comment: The raster clips as well as it can here, see picture added above. This was using the current QGIS Master under Ubuntu. I think it might be worth upgrading to QGIS 1.8.

Comment: I'll give that a try maybe I've got some code messed up somewhere.