# Error using GDAL to clip raster to KML (CRS is same for both): Cutline not of polygon type

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, kml, clip, error

I have a high-resolution, 4-band (RGBA) geo-tiff (22.26 Gb) with an image of an airport. I have a `KML` file that has a polygon for a runway. I used `Google Earth` to construct the `KML`. Both files use the same CRS and align properly in `QGIS` (i.e. the polygon perfectly outlines the runway when displayed together). I want to use `GDAL (version 3.2.0)` to clip the geo-tiff with the `KML` file, and I want the output to have a transparent background. But when I try I get an error:

```
ERROR 1: Cutline not of polygon type.
```

[This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39113/clipping-rasters-with-a-mask-layer-error) shows that errors can arise when the polygon and raster don't have the same CRS, but my KML and raster use the same CRS.

From the output of `ogrinfo` for the `KML`, I noticed the line `Geometry: Unknown (any)`, but I don't know if that's related to the error.

I tried converting the `KML` to an `ESRI shapefile` using `ogr2ogr`, but I get the same error.

**GDAL command:**

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline "RW1634.kml" -cl "RW1634.kml" -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -dstnodata -999.0 rw1634.tif rw1634_clipped.tif
```

**What could be causing this error and how do I fix it?**

Below are the outputs of `gdalinfo` for the raster and `ogrinfo` for the `KML`:

RASTER (`gdalinfo`)

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: rw1634.tif
Size is 51083, 108944
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-90.475312585529650,31.184756697157653)
Pixel Size = (0.000000134865000,-0.000000115954000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -90.4753126,  31.1847567) ( 90d28'31.13"W, 31d11' 5.12"N)
Lower Left  ( -90.4753126,  31.1721242) ( 90d28'31.13"W, 31d10'19.65"N)
Upper Right ( -90.4684233,  31.1847567) ( 90d28' 6.32"W, 31d11' 5.12"N)
Lower Right ( -90.4684233,  31.1721242) ( 90d28' 6.32"W, 31d10'19.65"N)
Center      ( -90.4718679,  31.1784405) ( 90d28'18.72"W, 31d10'42.39"N)
Band 1 Block=51083x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=51083x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=51083x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=51083x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

KML (`ogrinfo -al`)

```
INFO: Open of `RW1634.kml'
      using driver `LIBKML' successful.

Layer name: RW1634.kml
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-90.475312, 31.172124) - (-90.468423, 31.184757)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Name: String (0.0)
description: String (0.0)
timestamp: DateTime (0.0)
begin: DateTime (0.0)
end: DateTime (0.0)
altitudeMode: String (0.0)
tessellate: Integer (0.0)
extrude: Integer (0.0)
visibility: Integer (0.0)
drawOrder: Integer (0.0)
icon: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(RW1634.kml):1
  Name (String) = RW1634
  tessellate (Integer) = 1
  extrude (Integer) = 0
  visibility (Integer) = -1
  Style = @m_ylw-pushpin
  LINESTRING Z (-90.4753124912034 31.1846445852666 0,-90.4750229284792 31.1847566316438 0,-90.4749292579975 31.1845910350613 0,-90.4748288161075 31.1844036280404 0,-90.4747220906378 31.1842017736694 0,-90.474377266881 31.1835458629179 0,-90.4741249354232 31.1830610804011 0,-90.4734341410196 31.1817503059949 0,-90.4723932839778 31.1797706863484 0,-90.4716687193589 31.1783953646793 0,-90.4710184083647 31.177165151549 0,-90.4702268574338 31.1756583941818 0,-90.4698778621991 31.1749931231149 0,-90.4691750565429 31.1736696922447 0,-90.4687854807428 31.1729183421635 0,-90.4684231552055 31.1722403307614 0,-90.4687178791877 31.1721241739937 0,-90.4687308782668 31.1721487678317 0,-90.46895975626 31.1725817940356 0,-90.4691436041896 31.1729296206193 0,-90.4693965560035 31.1734138351111 0,-90.469811353387 31.1741933559874 0,-90.4702333646854 31.1750010829828 0,-90.4706513271147 31.1757963406044 0,-90.471554546709 31.1775061738734 0,-90.4720755486982 31.1784917566076 0,-90.4727430768749 31.1797585268031 0,-90.4733099660671 31.1808335216472 0,-90.4742753224242 31.1826732284418 0,-90.4746786439144 31.1834472945963 0,-90.4749918591061 31.184039731776 0,-90.4751268131754 31.184297946721 0,-90.4752248920029 31.1844834554095 0,-90.4752849205458 31.1845940361614 0,-90.4752864671578 31.1846010879602 0,-90.4752962104744 31.1846180162179 0,-90.4753007412126 31.1846250853319 0,-90.4753060875201 31.1846284456701 0,-90.4753124912034 31.1846445852666 0)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a polygon? Looks like a path (LineString).

Comment: Oh right, I see. It's a closed linestring, right? I'm still learning about the different shape formats. I'm following `Python Geospatial Development (2016 PACKT)`, which says that a polygon is "defined by a closed linestring" (p.33). Thanks @user2856 for helping me.

Comment: For anyone else who encounters `KML` files from `Google Earth` that use a closed LineString instead of a polygon, this http://gscplanning.github.io/tutorials/data/line2polygon.html describes a method for converting it to a polygon.